# How to combine two ResultSets in Java?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have two result sets (`rs1` and `rs2`) having same fields. Now how to combine those two result sets into one so that duplicate rows are shown once.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if the two `ResultSet`s are from the same database then why not combine them during the retrieval by using `union`; e.g.

```
select A, B
from C
union
select A, B
from D
```

However, if this is not an option then I suggest defining a `Row` class to represent a Row extracted from your `ResultSet` and implementing `equals` / `hashCode` to allow the `Row` to be compared for equality.  Then simply add each `Row` to a `Set` (e.g. `HashSet`) in order to remove duplicates.

Comment: +1 ... great answer ... very precise and to the point... I would upvote you 10 times if I had the rights.

Comment: UNION removes duplicates, forcing a sort.  UNION ALL functionally concatenates result sets.  If dups are acceptable or you know the two result sets have no overlap, use UNION ALL.

Comment: @Adam: The OP already stated he wanted duplicate rows to only be shown once, hence why I mentioned UNION rather than UNION ALL.

Answer (score 3):

You can:

1. Create a class that has properties corresponding to the columns
2. implement the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods using the fields by which you define "duplicate" (let your IDE help you with the generation of these)
3. createa a `Set` (`HashSet`):

   Set combinedDataSet = new HashSet();
4. Iterate each resultSet, and construct objects:

   ```
   while (rs1.next) {
       YourClass obj = new YourClass();
       obj.setSomeProperty(rs.getString(1));
       obj.setAnotherProperty(rs.getString(2));
       // etc..
       cominbedDataSet.add(obj);
   }
   ```

   The same iteration goes for `rs2`

Do this *only in case* you can't get the desired result via an SQL query!

Comment: @Bozho I want to communicate with you. I don't have any programming problems which I can post here. You have answered various questions of mine and thus, I know that you are the right person to have advice from you for my career. I checked your blog too but didn't find any way to communicate with you. I don't want to use SO to communicate with you as it would be wrong. I would be very grateful to you if you give me some time from your precious time and tell me how can I chat with you.
Thanks.

Comment: @Yatendra Goel if you have particular questions, ask them at SO. If you have less-particular questions, check my blog (linked in my profile here) and drop me a comment.